# The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form control

Tags: html, validation

I have some errors in my code
Here is my error:

> The for attribute of the label element must refer to a non-hidden form
>   control.

And myd code:

```html
<form action="/search">
  <span class="input input--hoshi search-wrapp main-page-open" style="display:block">
    <input class="input__field input__field--hoshi" type="text" id="search" name="keyword" placeholder="Search..."/>
    <label class="input__label input__label--hoshi input__label--hoshi-color-2" for="input-5">
      <!--<span class="input__label-content input__label-content-hoshi">Search...</span>-->
    </label>
    <span class="icon-serch"></span>
  </span>
  <input id="search-btn" type="submit" style="display: none;"/>
</form>
```

What is wrong with it? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The **label for** attribute  must contain the **input id** value

```
<label for="foo">Foo:</label>
<input id="foo">
```

To omit the **for** and **id** attributes all-together, put **input** inside **label**

```
<label>
    Foo: <input name="foo">
</label>
```

Also note, that **input** cannot be **hidden** `<input type="hidden">`, however it can be styled as hidden `<input style="display:none">`

Answer (score 0):

The validator is expecting for your label's `for` field to target the `id` field of the input element that contains it. Here, that means that `for="input-5"` is expected to be `for="search"`, as `<input>`'s id is `search`.

As you're expecting the user to add input to this field, you should be making sure they are linked to each other.